# Fastest way to count Django manytomanys?

Tags: django, database, optimization

What is the fastest way to count Django manytomanys?

I have hundreds of thousands rows of data, and I want to count answers.

Need are:

- how many objects where answer is not null
- and answer's counts per Option.

Models:

```
class Option(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

class MultiChoiceAnswer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(
        Option,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("options"),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

For counting use Django's [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) together with [`Count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#id9).
To filter for relations that are not null you can simply [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) all rows where the relation equals `None`.

```py
# Answers per Option
qs = Option.objects.annotate(answer_count=Count("multi_choice_answer_set"))
for option in qs:
    print(option, option.answer_count)

# Answers is not null
count = MultiChoiceAnswer.objects.exclude(answers=None).count()
```